# How should I update a scheduled selector's interval?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scheduled selector and I want to update the interval, I've tried calling

```
[self schedule:@selector(method) interval:1];
```

But it gives me this log:

> CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating
>   interval from: 0.12 to 1.00

Is it correct to do it like this or should I unschedule it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it.  Comments from `CCScheduler.h` :

*If the selector is already scheduled, then only the interval parameter will be updated without re-scheduling it again.*

Edit:
Since **cocos2d** is open-source, you can also just poke around in `CCScheduler.m` and see that it handles the case cleanly:

```
if( selector == timer->selector ) {
   CCLOG(@"CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: %.4f to %.4f", timer->interval, interval);
   timer->interval = interval;
   return;
}
```

Comment: And if this message bothers you (it really is superfluous) just comment it out. That's what I did.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D one of the other glorious benefits of open-source libraries!  Although, leaving it in has a (minor) benefit of helping you notice any cases where you think a selector isn't currently scheduled, schedule it (again), and the logging lets you find out that it already was.